# variable overflow when converting binary to decimals

Tags: c, binary

I'm coding a program that converts binary into decimal. When I get to power of 32 my variable overflows since it cannot hold this much info.

What should I do?

```
unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n = 0;
 
    while (bin[i]!='\0'){
        x = 1;
        n  = 1;
          
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
            x = x*2;
        }
      
        if (bin[i] == '0'){
            n = 0;
        }
          
        if (n == 1){
            if (bin[i] == '1'){
                temp = temp + x;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Here are my test numbers:

```
"0",
"1",
"00",
"01",
"10",
"11",
"111",
"0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
"1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Comment: Make `x` `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Aside: your function is a bit inefficient. For each digit it should only need to multiply `temp` by 2 (or shift left by 1) and add the new digit if it is `'1'`.

Comment: A) Try and give your variables meaningful names so we can understand the intent here. B) Remove excessive blank lines which serve no purpose other than to obscure your code beneath a scrolling section.

Comment: out of the remark of @IanAbbott why do you compute *x* when is is useless ? why no 'else' rather than to test again ? you do not need all that stuff about *n*. Your code can be 5 times shorter

Comment: @bruno Idk why about the x it was a very good point and for the reason about the code being inefficient/long was cause I rewrote this multiple times and I just had copies so I would copy and paste snippets of my old codes and combine them. I was going to clean it up

Comment: @MohamedElMoursi  please look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I get to power of 32, my variable overflows since it cannot hold this much info. What should I do?

all depends on the size of the unsigned number you use to memorize the result, if your number has 32bits you are limited to 32bits too.

The number of bits for the unsigned type *T* is given by :

```
 sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT
```

Note you have types allowing to have the expected number of bits whatever the compiler / CPU : `uint32_t` has 32b, `uint64_t` has 64b etc

---

Out of that you have several problems in your code, the main problem is your convert is wrong, for instance the input "100...000" will return 1 whatever the number of 0 you have, that because of that wrong (and useless) loop :

```
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
        x = x*2;
    }
```

which supposes the number in binary is given in reverse order because the very first digit is considered to give the value 1 or 0, the second the value 2 or 0, the third 4 or 0 etc.

If you want to use that loop as it is you need to go through the input from the last character down to the first, not from the first up to the last.

---

Out of that your code is complicated for nothing and manages too many variable and does to many tests, just look at the logic of that part of the code :

```
    n  = 1;
      
    ...compute x
  
    if (bin[i] == '0'){
        n = 0;
    }
      
    if (n == 1){
        if (bin[i] == '1'){
            temp = temp + x;
        }
    }
```

if `(bin[i] == '0')` is true *n* is modified from 1 to 0, that means it is impossible to have both `(bin[i] == '0')` and `(n == 1)` so `if (n == 1)` can be replaced by `else` :

```
    n  = 1;
      
    ...compute x
  
    if (bin[i] == '0'){
        n = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (bin[i] == '1'){
            temp = temp + x;
        }
    }
```

now we see *n* is only assigned but never used, so it can be removed :

```
    ...compute x
  
    if (bin[i] == '0'){
        /* nothing */
    }
    else {
        if (bin[i] == '1'){
            temp = temp + x;
        }
    }
```

to test `(bin[i] == '0')` is clearly useless because nothing is done when it is true, the code is now :

```
    ...compute x
    if (bin[i] == '1'){
      temp = temp + x;
    }
```

as you can see the value of *x* is useless except when `(bin[i] == '1')`is true, so it is useless to compute it before to know `(bin[i] == '1')` is true, so :

```
if (bin[i] == '1'){
  ...compute x
  temp = temp + x;
}
```

Out of the fact the value of *x* is not the expected one note on the first loop it values 1, then on the second loop 2, then 4 etc, so you do not have to do the internal loop and just have to initialize *x* with 1 before the loop then to multiply it by 2 at the end of the loop, and your function is now :

```
unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 1;
 
    while (bin[i]!='\0'){
       if (bin[i] == '1'){
         temp += x;
       }
       i++;
       x *= 2;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

as you can see the code is very reduced compared to yours, even it does exactly the same thing.

Note your code consider any character different than '1' to be '0', so "1az" is considered to be "100".

---

Now the right code (out of using *strtoll* or any other builtin function), your error is to multiply *x* by 2 each time rather than to multiply *temp* :

```
unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
 
    while (bin[i]!='\0') {
       temp *= 2;
       if (bin[i] == '1'){
         temp += 1;
       }
       i++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

or more compact :

```
unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
 
    while (bin[i]!='\0')
       temp = temp*2 + (bin[i++] == '1');
    return temp;
}
```

still managing any character different than '1' as '0'.

So

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
 
    while (bin[i]!='\0')
       temp = temp*2 + (bin[i++] == '1');
    return temp;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  while (--argc)
  {
    printf("%s => %llu\n", argv[1], conver(argv[1]));
    argv += 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 1 100 110 1010101010
1 => 1
100 => 4
110 => 6
1010101010 => 682
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note it is also possible to remove the variable *i*:

```
unsigned long long conver( char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
 
    while (*bin != '\0')
       temp = temp*2 + (*bin++ == '1');
    return temp;
}
```

and because you do not modify the content of *bin* :

```
unsigned long long conver( const char *bin ){
    unsigned long long temp = 0;
 
    while (*bin != '\0')
       temp = temp*2 + (*bin++ == '1');
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to code the routine yourself you can use [`strtoull`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) which can convert at least `64` bit values from binary to decimal and, depending on the plarform limits, even more, it also provides you tools to safely check the validity of the string to be converted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    errno = 0; // reset errno
    unsigned long long value;
    char *endptr;
    char str[] = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";

    value = strtoull(str, &endptr, 2);

    if(errno == ERANGE){ //value too large
        perror("Overflow");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(*endptr != '\0'){ //if str has invalid characters
        puts("Invalid value");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%llu", value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615
```

<kbd>**[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FwCGQ9MeIEnFHIUb)**</kbd>

Comment: hello so the code works for most of them except the last one which is 64 * 1. the output for it is suppose to be 18446744073709551615.

Comment: To get that, @MohamedElMoursi, you need appropriate changes to use `unsigned long long`.  Quite a lot of changes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if its alright may I have some tips to lead me to the right direction?

Comment: When is `str[strlen(str)]` not the same as `’\0’`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im honestly very brand new to coding I have no idea

Comment: @MohamedElMoursi — the question about the thanks byte was aimed at anastaciu.  It's a rhetorical question; the answer is ”never” by the definition of string lengths.  I will address your question in the comments soon.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So just I did little research but I fixed it since stroll is meant for a long int I switched it over for  strtoull which handles unsigned long long int and it worked

Comment: @MohamedElMoursi — You'd change the type of `value` to `unsigned long long`; you'd change the function to `strtoull()`; you'd change the print format to `"%llu\n"` (the newline is a good idea; the change from `d` to `u` is crucial).  The value of `errno` would be zero on entry to `main()` but if it was in any other function, it would be crucial to set `errno` to zero before calling `strtoull()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, strlen is unneedded, I'll change that.

Comment: @henwanyo — changing your user name means that comments addressed to your old name aren't obviously addressed to you.  Just an FYI.  The information remains valid.  I'm puzzled about how the spell mangler on my cell phone changed null into thanks!).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, hahaha I thought that was strange, you  must have an iPhone fo sure :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, anyway, it has nice ring to it, maybe you're starting a trend here.